# Android: Is it possible to prevent a specific activity from handling an intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, picker

My android application starts an intent consisting of a video file.  One thing I'm trying to do is prevent the build in video player from handling this intent.  Instead I only want third party players to be chosen to play this file.  Anyone know if there is any way to create an implicit intent and prevent certain activities/applications from being selected to open the intent?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass custom object in Intent for **eg** a `string` that notifies the `activity` that it is being called by your App since other apps are not passing that custom object you can have check in `onCreate` while filtering `Intent` and thus check for that custom object if its present then go else `finish` the `activity`